Tengo este error al en GO con CompileDaemon

ya tengo ejecutado go get github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon
pero no puedo compilar mi Variable de entorno tiene GOPATH go/bin

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

No se mucho de Go, pero no tiene que ser go install en vez de go get?
